# WSDL access through untrusted https request for iOS

Tags: ios, soap, https, wsdl, keychain

So the scenario is I want to connect to a server by using WSDL, and the access point start with "https" which blocked me out.

And now I got stucked on the last step, which is to **retrieve and save secTrustRef to keychain**

**Some pre setup**

I have used the sudze service to generate WSDL wrapper and it works fine under http.

And I follow this tutorial until I figure out that the keychainmanager class is not part of the class.

http://blog.exadel.com/working-with-ios-and-soap/

So I need to do some reverse engineering to implement the method to save the server trust object into keychain, which should implement the similar functionality to replace

```
[[KeyChainManager sharedManager] isSavedTrust:confirmNeed.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
```

and

```
[[KeyChainManager sharedManager] saveCertificatesFromTrust:confirmNeed.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
```

It seems I am quite close to what I want to achieve by using this sample code, but I am quite new to the security framework...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html

Anyone familiar with security frame work could help me out?